# What is the language behind this game?

Tags: java, game-engine, webgl

I stumbled upon this GWT Quake 2 port for the browsers:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyfu4OwjUEI

Is it really made in Java? Or something else, like JavaScript perhaps, since it's using WebGL API?

Answer (score 4):

Quote from the project page:

> The port is based on the Jake2 project, compiled to Javascript using the Google Web Toolkit (GWT). Jake 2 is a Java port of the original Quake II source code, which was open sourced by id software.

Comment: Yup, Java compiled to JavaScript using GWT.  The implementation uses WebGL, which is a JS binding of OpenGL ES 2.0, so it will also use vertex and fragment shaders written in GLSL.

Answer (score 2):

No, javascript. But the link has a description that sends you here: http://code.google.com/p/quake2-gwt-port/

that explains what happens....

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember they used some tool to translate the C code to Java and then by using GWT translating the Java to Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is Java, since they used [Jake2](http://bytonic.de/html/jake2.html), which is Quake2 engine port to Java. Using this port, they embedded it in a browser using HTML5 features.